# How to implement Aly's permutation test for comparison of variances in R?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, permutation-test

The excerpt below is from "Permutation, Parametric and Bootstrap Tests of Hypotheses", Third Ed. by Phillip Good (pages 58-61), section 3.7.2..

I am trying to implement this permutation test in R (see further below) to compare two variances. I am thinking now about how to calculate the p-value, and whether the test allows for different alternative hypothesis (greater, less, two-sided) and I am not sure on how to proceed.

Could you shed some light on this and perhaps give me some criticism about the code? Many thanks!

[image]

```
# Aly's non-parametric, permutation test of equality of variances
# From "Permutation, Parametric and Bootstrap Tests of Hypotheses", Third Ed. 
# by Phillip Good (pages 58-61), section 3.7.2.

# Implementation of delta statistic as defined by formula in page 60
# x_{i}, order statistics
# z = x_{i+1} - x_{i}, differences between successive order statistics
aly_delta_statistic <- function(z) {
  z_length <- length(z)
  m <- z_length + 1
  i <- 1:z_length
  sum(i*(m-i)*z)
}

aly_test_statistic <- function(sample1, sample2 = NULL, nperm = 1) {

  # compute statistic based on one sample only: sample1
  if(is.null(sample2)) {
    sample1 <- sort(sample1)
    z <- diff(sample1)
    return(aly_delta_statistic(z))
  }

  # statistic based on randomization of the two samples
  else {
    m1 <- length(sample1)
    m2 <- length(sample2)
    # allocate a vector to save the statistic delta
    statistic <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = nperm)
    for(j in 1:nperm) {
      # 1st stage resampling (performed only if samples sizes are different)
      # larger sample is resized to the size of the smaller
      if(m2 > m1) {
         sample2 <- sort(sample(sample2, m1))
         m <- m1
      } else {
         sample1 <- sort(sample(sample1, m2))
         m <- m2
      }
      # z-values: z1 in column 1 and z2 in column 2.
      z_two_samples <- matrix(c(diff(sample1), diff(sample2)), ncol = 2)
      # 2nd stage resampling
      z <- apply(z_two_samples, 1, sample, 1)
      statistic[j] <- aly_delta_statistic(z)
    }
    return(statistic)
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think you can test equality against the possibility that population 1 has a variance larger than population 2 or less than population 2 or if you have no reason to expect the result one way or the other.

In the text it seems that Phil is doing a two-sided test because he talks about as extreme or more extreme value than you get under the null hypothesis.  If it was one-sided he should say as large or larger or on the other side as small or smaller.  As he finds only 2 out of the 16 possible permutations he gets a p-value of 2/16 = 0.125. He then says accept the null hypothesis whereas many of us would prefer to say do not reject.

Regarding the R code I am not an expert in R so I cannot tell you about the accuracy of the code.  If it was taken from the book it is likely correct or there would probably be an errata sheet with a correction.

Whether you use a parametric test for the equality of the variances or non-parametric approaches like bootstrap or permutation tests it is very difficult to reject the null hypothesis with small sample sizes especially 4 samples in each group as Phil did here.  But I think he did it for simplicity to explain the method simply and thoroughly.

Comment: The code is my own. I would like to have this test implemented in R and the code in the OP is my first approach at it. However I am not sure about a few aspects of the test. For instance, the book takes sample 1 as the one to calculate the observed/reference statistic, and uses permutations involving the two samples to find the statistic distribution under the null hypothesis. I am unsure if one needs to pick one of the samples as the reference or not. I would find it strange that there would be such an asymmetry...

Comment: From the book, it seems the test is two-sided... However I remember reading that one can only do a two-sided test if the statistic distribution has two tails. The statistic $\delta$ seems to fall in the range from 0 to Inf, so it ought not to have a left tail... Challenging, I reckon,  the concept of existing a two-sided alternative hypothesis for this test...

Comment: The null hypothesis is equality of variances so it doesn't matter which statistic is first.

Comment: Even if the two samples are not equal in size?

Comment: BTW, did you say that 2/16 is 0.25 by mistake or were you multiplying 0.125 by 2 because of the two-sidedness of the test?

Comment: In the case of unequal sample size the two samples are pooled because under the null hypothesis the distributions are equal.

Comment: They're pooled but prior to pooling the bigger one is resized to the size of the smaller one, right?

Comment: @plant I am very sorry of course 1/8 =0.125 but the null hypothesis would still not be rejected.  I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: In principle, I agree with you that the test should be about equality of variances, i.e. it is symmetric and hence it should not matter which sample is chosen as reference. Yet, I cannot reconcile that fact with this passage: _with 2 out of 16 rearrangements yielding values of the statistic **as, or more, extreme than the original**, we should accept the null hypothesis_, as this passage, to me, suggests that the alternative is necessarily one-sided.

Comment: don't you mind up voting my question to draw more attention?

Comment: Extreme can be extremely high or extremely low.  That is why I made the comment large or larger and small or smaller for the two possible one-sided tests.

Comment: Sure I think it is a good enough question.  I will do that.  Not sure that will bring more attention.  The post has not been up very long.

Comment: If you at some point find my answer the best you can use the check mark to accept it.